# Downgrade to react 15.6.2 from react 16.2.0 failed

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I recently upgraded to react `16.2.0` from react `15.6.2`
Now my application doesnt work as expected and has lot of warnings for dependancies on react `15.6.2`
So for me now its not possible to upgrade all other dependencies to `16.2.0.` because of the time schedule.
Hence I want to downgrade to react `15.6.2`

I ran following commands to install react 15.6.2 again:

```
npm install react@^15.6.2
```

I am getting following error :

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.6.2 invalid
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@16.2.0
```

When I update my package.json to `"react": "^15.6.2"`, I get following error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/rakesh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.4/bin/node" "/home/rakesh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.4/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/rakesh/rockethire/development/codebase/recruitment/rh-react/npm-debug.log
```

Below is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "rh-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Pages accessible for outside world",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "sh -ac '. .env; webpack -d'",
    "build:test": "sh -ac '. .env.test; webpack -p'",
    "build:prod": "sh -ac '. .env.prod; webpack -p'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ag-grid": "^13.3.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "^13.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "fsevents": "^1.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "query-string": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-async-script-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "react-click-outside": "^3.0.0",
    "react-cookies": "^0.1.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.61.0",
    "react-datetime": "^2.11.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom-factories": "^1.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.3",
    "react-dropzone-component": "^3.0.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.6.5",
    "react-notifications": "^1.4.3",
    "react-nvd3": "^0.5.7",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.17",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "react-select2-wrapper": "^1.0.4-beta5",
    "reactjs-localstorage": "0.0.5",
    "webpack": "^3.9.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^4.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

Anyone has idea why I am unable to downgrade?

Comment: Run npm install command again once you make changes to your package.json file.

Manually change the version in the package.json file to 15.6.2  for 'react' and run npm install again to reflect the changes

Comment: Hi @HarshMakadia, thanks for the response. I tried manually updating the package.json and then running the npm-install command but got an error. That is already mentioned in the question above.

Comment: You need to run npm install instead of npm-install.

Comment: Next time you upgrade dependencies, you should check your code into a version control system. Then you can upgrade and reset everything if anything goes wrong. Developing without a VCS is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @HarshMakadia Sorry for the typo but I ran npm install only.

Comment: @nkr yes from next time I will definately add this to VCS. Any idea how to resolve  this now?

Comment: If you set up your `package.json` correctly, you can remove the `node_modules` (better rename it to something else for now) and then run `npm install`. Remember to remove `package-lock.json` as well.

Comment: Hi @nkr, I renamed my `node_modules` folder and ran `npm install`. It gives me following error :   `npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/rakesh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.4/bin/node" "/home/rakesh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.4/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})`

Comment: `fsevents` is Mac-only. On my platform (Win10) it only gives me a warning, not an error. Just try to run it. If it doesn't work, clean your npm caches. For the future also try to regularly check if your dependencies in package.json are correct and your code would run with a simple npm install.

Comment: Hi @nkr, my npm install ran successfully with `sudo npm install`. But it gave lot of warnings. My code built successfully with `npm run build`. But now when I run my application it gives me below errors:  1.`Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method`  2.`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$z6r26ib5q9a' of null`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed this issue with the help of `@HarshMakadia` and `@nkr`.Thanks to both of them. Here is the solution for any other person facing the same problem.

1.Delete/Rename your current `node_modules` folder.
2.Run `npm cache clean` / `sudo npm cache clean`(Ubuntu 14.04)
3.Manually update your `package.json` to change version of react and react-dom from 16.0.2 to 15.6.2
4.Run `npm install`/`sudo npm install`(Ubuntu 14.04)

Note: Add your node_modules folder to any VCS like git to prevent from such issue