# How do I un upgrade react/react-dom from 16.13.1 to 15.6.2?

Tags: javascript

[image]When I type

```
npm view react version
```

I get 16.13.1.

How can I fix this? I need to use 15.6.2

I already tried npm install @. I think I have 15.6.2 but the newer react version of 16.13.1 is overriding it. How can I fix this?

Comment: update the version in the package.json for both react and react-dom and run `npm install`. You might have to do changes in your code given there's a breaking change. For that, check out the [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to see anything impacts you

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Am I allowed to do that. My advisor (I'm a HS intern) gave me the package.json and idt I can edit that. Is there any way for me to just go down to 15.6.2?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:
npm install react@version

look at this solution:
[How to install a previous exact version of a NPM package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/how-to-install-a-previous-exact-version-of-a-npm-package)

Comment: I tried that and it says: + react@15.6.2
updated 1 package and audited 3541 packages in 37.44s. But when I typed in npm view react version , I get 16.13.1.

Comment: Do I need to delete 16.13.1.?

Comment: can you post your package.json file? and you could try npm install packge@version --save

Comment: I did npm install and basically it downloaded all these dependencies except the following: ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@15.6.2, ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.6.2, ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@5.16.0, ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@4.44.2. I'm not sure why though. It's been frustrating me all morning.

Comment: I tried npm install packge@version --save  and it unfortunately doesn't work. I think it downloaded but the newer 16.13.1 version is overriding it or something

Comment: I guess the problem is coming from that react-dom depends ion the react version so you should downgrade them both together

Comment: So npm install react@version react-dom@version?

Comment: check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252594/downgrade-to-react-15-6-2-from-react-16-2-0-failed